# Does Ruby have a similar function to pluck(arr, key) in Lodash?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, lodash

Given an really big array/hash, for example, users:

```
users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 },
  { 'user': 'jeff',   'age': 32 },
  ...
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40 }
];
```

If you apply Lodash's `pluck` function*:

```
_.pluck(users, 'user');
```

You get this result:

```
-> ['barney', 'jeff', ..., 'fred']
```

Does Ruby have a similarly convenient function that will get only a certain key of the array/hash without iterating it? I know Rails has a function called pluck but it is for ActiveRecords. Any suggestions for how to accomplish this on arrays?

<sub>*`pluck` was apparently [replaced by `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136306/what-happened-to-lodash-pluck) since this question was written</sub>

Comment: I know I answered already, but it's actually not clear what language you're asking about. The title leads me to believe Ruby, but the code samples look like javascript.

Comment: Yes, im asking about Ruby, but the example was taken from JS, with a example in JS in order to be clear what I would want to have in Ruby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is on in the standard library, but it is easy to accomplish this with a block:

```
users.map { |element| element[:user] }
```

P.S.: since you used the colon style hash, each key in your hash is a symbol, and must be accessed as element[:].

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want `#map`, which takes each element of an array and replaces it with the result of a block.

```
users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 },
  { 'user': 'jeff', 'age': 32 },
  ...
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40 }
]

users.map {|u| u['user'] } # => ['barney', 'jeff', ..., 'fred']
```