# Combining Lodash Methods

Tags: javascript, filter, lodash

Is it possible to combine a ._max and a pluck?

Finding Max Works and returns an object with the highest scoreLabel

```
var maxScore = _.max(peopleList, scoreLabel);
```

But combining it with pluck returns a list of undefined

```
_.pluck(_.max(peopleList, scoreLabel), scoreLabel);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `_.pluck` is to retrieve a field *for each* object in a collection - since `_.max` returns only a single object, you don't need to pluck, you can simply retrieve the field from the one object you have:

```
var maxScore = _.max(peopleList, scoreLabel)[scoreLabel];
```

The above will retrieve the person from `peopleList` who has the largest `scoreLabel`, and then retrieve that person's `scoreLabel` value.

Alternatively, you could swap the *order* of the calls to `_.max` and `_.pluck`, like this:

```
var maxScore = _.max(_.pluck(peopleList, scoreLabel));
```

This will build a collection of *all* the `scoreLabel` values, and then retrieve the largest one.

Answer (score 1):

`_.max(peopleList, scoreLabel)` returns a person, not a collection of people, so you can simply access its `scoreLabel` property using bracket notation to get the `maxScore`.

```
var maxScore = _.max(peopleList, scoreLabel)[scoreLabel]
```

It looks like [`_.pluck` has also been deprecated in favor of `_.map(list, 'property')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136306/what-happened-to-lodash-pluck) for the latest version of Lodash.